# Building QML applications from command line (without Qt Creator)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, g++, qml, qmake

I'm writing a QML application using Qt 5.7 on Ubuntu 14.04. I prefer to use an editor other than Qt Creator, so it makes it slightly cumbersome to launch Qt Creator and switch to it just to press Ctrl-R each time I want to run. I'd like to compile and launch my app from the command line.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30564064/405017) and then [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/424198/11844) I was able to install `qmake` and make it the default:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6132530/405017) I am copying the `qmake` build command listed by Qt Creator in the Project tab and successfully building the make file:

```
qmake qt-client.pro -r -spec linux-g++
```

However, when I run `make` (on my already-working-in-Qt-Creator code) I get:

```
phrogz@Slub:~/Code/rb3jay/qt-client$ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtQuick -I/usr/include/qt5/QtQml -I/usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:6:36: error: ‘AA_EnableHighDpiScaling’ is not a member of ‘Qt’
     QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
                                    ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I'm *guessing* that perhaps the version of Qt being picked up by `qmake` or `g++` is not the 5.7 version Qt Creator is using, since `AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` was [added in Qt 5.6](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html).

The [full generated Makefile](https://gist.github.com/Phrogz/0e51790f4fe71338bf1b54a72ec567d5) includes 
99 references to `/usr/include/qt5` and 179 references to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5`. Qt 5.7 is installed in `/home/phrogz/Qt5.7.0`. Obviously I need to modify something in the qmake command to get this pointing elsewhere.

How can I get this to work? Do I need to somehow remove an older version of qt libraries installed by Ubuntu? Point some configuration to the version of Qt 5.7 that's now installed (by the Qt Installer) in my home directory? Replace existing/old Qt directories with symlinks?

Comment: Try setting/modifying the [`INCLUDEPATH`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qmake-project-files.html) variable in your `qt-client.pro` file.

Comment: You need to run qmake from the Qt 5.7 installation. It's there in `/home/phrogz/Qt5.7.0`.

Comment: @jpnurmi That did the trick, thank you. If you choose to post that as an answer, perhaps you might elaborate on why `/home/phrogz/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake` works, but a soft link to that file placed in `/usr/local/bin` (and preferred in the `PATH`) produces a failure similar to (but not identical) to that seen above.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)

project(myproject)

find_package(Qt5 5.7.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Core
    Quick
    Widgets
)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Quick
    Qt5::Widgets
)
```