# How do I know which console command Qt is building the project on?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, build, nmake

My project unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127357/building-qt-creator-projects-from-command-line) issue is going through MSVC and I'm having troubles with nmake. Is there a way to just see what commands Qt Creator uses when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>?

Comment: What kind of problems with `nmake` do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply click down on the "Compile Output" pane, and it will show you the exact commands that are issued to build the project.